# How to easily serve static files over HTTPS locally

Tags: apache, http, https

We have frontend and backend developers. For now, frontend developers have to get running all the backend stuff on their computers, which can be quite heavy to run/compile.

I'm trying to see how to lighten this dev process by setting up an integration server on which the frontend developers will be able to plug their locally served files.

Basically a frontend developer will go to an url like `https://integration.company.com/?baseStaticAssetUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080` so that the developer can specify where the backend should get the JS/CSS files.

This works fine except with HTTPS because you can't load JS files with HTTP if the backend html file was loaded with HTTPS.

Chrome complains:

> [blocked] The page at
>   'https://integration.company.com/?baseStaticAssetUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.host%3A8080'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
>   'http://local.host:8080/app.css': this content should also be loaded
>   over HTTPS.

For reasons specific to our business, I'd like to keep the HTTPS enabled (switching from HTTP to HTTPS already let us to unexpected errors due to browser security).

For these reasons, I wonder if it is easily possible to setup an HTTPS server locally.

For HTTP it's pretty simple (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer $PORT`) but for HTTPS is there any simple solution (or should I use something like Apache)? I guess I will have to get certificates for localhost domain or something?

Do you see any other alternative to serving files in HTTPS that could solve my problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and get a https proxy address.

```
ngrok http $port
```

**Update May-2020**: [Caddy v2](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https) supports local https.

Comment: thanks yes I already know Ngrok but never though about using it to expose easily local content with https :) nice trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did not notice until now but when the Chrome restriction happens, there's a little shield icon on the Chrome url bar. Clicking it permits to remove the restriction so that HTTP content can be loaded from an HTTPS served page if the user really wants to. This solves my problem as I don't need anymore to serve HTTPS files locally.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple ways for doing it based which Language/Framework/System you like more.

The basic steps are:

1. Generate ssl certificate (replacing CN=localhost.ssl with your desired domain) `openssl req -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -subj \
   "/C=GC/ST=Garbage/L=Collector/O=ProgrammerMan/OU=Codeland/CN=localhost.ssl/emailAddress=me@example.com" \
   -keyout localhost.ssl.key -out localhost.ssl.cert`
2. Start web server with generated certificate to serve files from your desired folder. Example config for nginx is provided below

Example config for getting nginx to serve the same *webapp* folder over *3002* port. Https is turned on with the *ssl* keyword in *listen* instruction. Also the *ssl_certificate* and *ssl_certificate_key* are important. `start` `stop` and `reload` files are provided for your conveniency. They allow starting the nginx example in self-contained way and isolated in case there is nginx already running on the machine.

```
error_log  error.log;
pid        nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  # Usually nginx has much more comprehensive list of mime types
  # But to keep the example self contained, here are some essential
  # definitions
  types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    image/png                             png;
  }

  server {
    listen              3002 ssl;
    server_name         localhost.ssl;
    ssl_certificate     ../localhost.ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key ../localhost.ssl.key;

    root ../webapp;

    location / {
      autoindex on;
      index index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Save the config in `localhost.ssl` file, put your files in `webapp` folder and start nginx with `nginx -p`pwd`-c localhost.ssl`

I also wrote an blog post on this topic [Serving web application locally over https](https://mad.is/2016/01/serving-webapp-locally-over-https/)